# What is this skill move performed by Neymar called?

Tags: football, terminology, technique

In the following [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=e0X2K1dQIUg&t=0m33s), Neymar does a double step-over from a dead stop by adding a touch, finishing with a body feint. What is this skill move called?

Answer (score 1):

According to this video its called double stepover but i dont think that this is the offical name for it.

Comment: Why do you think this isn't the official name for it?

Answer (score 0):

This move appears similar if not identical to the "half preki", as demonstrated in this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7XUn-6x3O1Y).

In this move, the player dribbles the ball with the inside of one foot (we'll say the right foot), and then oversteps the shot with the left foot before cutting back.

Answer (score -1):

Its called "Shupaneyo". The word is only used in Brazil and some other Latin American countries. Don't know how it is called in English, but that is the original name

Comment: Searching "Shupaneyo" on Google didn't return a single result. Can you give some references? Portuguese ones are also fine.